# Sumar una columna de años a una columna de fecha en scala spark

Tags: date, dataframe, scala, spark

Mi problema es el siguiente

tengo dos campos uno de formato fecha y uno de valor entero (fecha y anio)
en este caso lo que quiero hacer es que a mi campo de fecha le sume los años que tiene mi campo anio, pero tomando en cuenta los años bisiestos.

```
+---------------------+----------------+
|fecha                |anio            |
+---------------------+----------------+
|           2011-02-28|               5|
+---------------------+----------------+
```

por lo que opte por lo siguiente:

primero, a mi campo de anio lo multiplico por 12 para obtener los meses que equivalen a mis años, posterior realizo un select expresion y le agrego los meses a mi fecha con la funcion add_months y
todo parece que va bien, obtengo bien las fechas esperadas, pero cuando reviso, unos casos donde mi fecha es 2011-02-28 , encuentro que no esta haciendo correcta la suma.

Ejemplo:
`selectExpr("*","add_months(fecha,anio_por_mes) as fecha_anio")`

**FECHA DONDE APLICA CORRECTO LA SUMATORIA :**

```
+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|fecha                |anio            |anio_por_mes   |fecha_anio      |
+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|           2011-11-23|              31|            372|      2042-11-23|
+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

**FECHA DONDE APLICA INCORRECTO LA SUMATORIA :**

```
+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|fecha                |anio            |anio_por_mes   |fecha_anio      |
+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|           2011-02-28|               5|             60|      2016-02-29|
+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Existe alguna forma de sumar directamente los años a la fecha?

Estuve buscando, pero no encontré alguna función de spark que me lo permita.

las versiones que tengo son :

**spark  2.4.8**

**scala 2.11.12**

De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

ya encontré la solución, la cual fue crear un UDF, que sume el año a la fecha.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import java.util.Calendar
import scala.language.postfixOps
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

// Método que realiza la suma del año a una fecha
def addDaysPolTrad(fechainicial:String, anio:String) :String = {
      try {
        val formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        
        val date = formato.parse(fechainicial)
        
        val calendario = Calendar.getInstance()

        val anioASumar = anio.toInt

        calendario.setTime(date)
        calendario.add(Calendar.YEAR, anioASumar)
        
        val nuewYeardate = calendario.getTime

        var fechaSumada = formato.format(nuewYeardate)

        var fechafinal = fechaSumada

        return fechafinal
          } catch { case e: Exception => "" }
    }

// Variable que almacena el resultado que devvuelve el método
 val addDaysPolTradUDF = 
        udf((fechainicial: String,anio: String) => (addDaysPolTrad(fechainicial,anio)))

//Para este ejemplo cree la fecha, pero puede tomarse de un campo de tu df
    val dt: DateTime = new DateTime("2011-02-28")
    val dateSub: String = dt.toString.substring(0, 10)
    
    import spark.implicits._

//DataFrame ejemplo
    val tabla = Seq(5).toDF("anio").
      withColumn("fecha",lit(dateSub))

// se agrega como una nueva columna a tu df, 
//indicando tus campos que tomara como los parámetros de entra
    val tablaFinal = tabla.
        select(
            col("fecha"),
            col("anio")).
        withColumn("fecha_add_anio",addDaysPolTradUDF(col("fecha"),col("anio")))
```

al realizar el show a tu tabla, el resultado es el siguiente

```
tablaFinal.show()
+----------+----+--------------+
|     fecha|anio|fecha_add_anio|
+----------+----+--------------+
|2011-02-28|   5|    2016-02-28|
+----------+----+--------------+
```

Espero les sirva, ya tenía días intentado y no me salía, pero con ayuda...se pudo.

Saludos!